# Odoo POS adding a product to checkout appears with quantity zero instead of one and does not allow to change product quantity

Tags: odoo

Adding a product at checkout in POS should appear with quantity 1 but appears with quantity 0 and it does not allow to change product quantity. Price is correct but since quantity is zero total price for the ticket is always zero.

[image]

Odoo 14 2023-01-26, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Firefox 109.0 Evrything was update today to latest version after this error but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the unit of measure (pieza). The precision conversion was changed from 0.01000 to 40.03000. Once it was returned to original value everything worked as normal.